# How do you find the parameters for conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=, user=, password=, host = )

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I pushed a Python / Django app to Heroku. The app uses a Postgres database. I now want to access this database from a Raspberry Pi running a simple Python program using

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=, user=, password=, host = )
```

The app used SQLite originally until pushed to Heroku. 
How do you find the parameters to use for `dbname=, user=, password=, host =`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku will [set an environment variable `DATABASE_URL`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres):

> As part of the provisioning process, a `DATABASE_URL` config var is added to your app’s configuration. This contains the URL your app uses to access the database.

You should use that to connect, since your credentials can change without notice. `psycopg2` can use this value directly, e.g.

```
import os
import psycopg2

database_url = os.getenv(
    'DATABASE_URL',
    default='postgres://localhost/postgres',  # E.g., for local dev
)

connection = psycopg2.connect(database_url)
```

**Edit:** Your Raspberry Pi application won't have access to this directly, but you can use the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) to query your config vars:

```
heroku config:get DATABASE_URL --app your-heroku-app-name
```

Something like this should work from recent versions of Python:

```
import subprocess

database_url = subprocess.run(
    ['heroku', 'config:get', 'DATABASE_URL', '--app', 'your-heroku-app-name'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
).stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to https://data.heroku.com/
2. Select your database.
3. Select the <kbd>Settings</kbd> tab.
4. Click <kbd>View Credentials</kbd>.

You should be able to see host, database name, user, port, and password.

See also: [Heroku Postgres Credentials](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials)

Comment: But those values are [subject to change at any time](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres). Credentials shouldn't be hard-coded on Heroku. Use the provided environment variables instead.

Comment: The subprocess.run method worked fine. Thanks Chris. Cheers, TrebleJ, this is good for short term, but heroku can move your app.